# Pandas, transforming rows that have the same datetime index value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, transformation

Currently I'm working with a dataframe of a few million rows and 8 columns and am trying to avoid the usage of loops while doing transformations on this df.

The problem is as follows.

An example format of the original Pandas DataFrame is shown below. Here 'index' is datetime, 'Room' is categorical and the other columns are floats.

Original df:

[image: original df]

This is sensor data in one dataframe, where there are multiple samples per datetime index value because there are multiple rooms. The target column should be of the following format.

[image: target shape]

Notice that i left out the columns for 'kitchen & living room'. You probably get the goal. One column per variable, per room label.

Now, to make things more complicated. In each timestep not all possible room categories might be visible. For example, at 20:05 'kitchen' might be missing from the example df.

One could see this transformation (i guess) as multiple dataframes (one df per room), being joined on the same datetime index, where each column name changes to `sensor__room_category`. Can this transformation be done without the usage of loops and iterating over the whole df? If so, how?

Another thing, in reality this df consists of the above data from multiple houses. So there is a column with 'house_1, house_2, house_3, ...' labels. So only the date from for example house_1 should be transformed, then house_2 etc... So the data per house stays separated.

I get that this is quite some specific question. But i wonder if there is some Pandas or maybe even np magic that makes easily doable.

TLDR: Data from sensors in different rooms needs to be transformed so there is one timestamp per value `sensor__room_category`. How to do this without massive loops?

Comment: I'm guessing this might be done by creating a filter mask (df[df[timestamp==value]]) so that you can have a new df for each timestamp you're interested in which lists only the rooms that have data for that timestamp, but I'm not sure I understand what your expected output is.
Anyhow, even if using Pandas function without implementing anything yourself the looping is going to happen, hence if speed is of the utmost importance you can try to chain together Pandas functions until you get your result, but in the other case implementing your specific solution might be easier but more time consumin

Comment: I would just set your datetime and house column as the index and then do `df.pivot('Room')` this will give you a multi-indexed dataframe that accomplishes what you are looking for...for the most part

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example

let's assume this multi indexed dataframe with datetime and house as index:

```
                         co2 humidity presence  room
index            house              
22/11/2018 20:00 house1 102    60        0  bedroom1
                 house1 104    62        0  bedroom2
                 house1 122    71        1  kitchen
                 house1 115    61        1  living room
22/11/2018 20:05 house1 103    64        0  bedroom1
                 house1 104    68        0  bedroom2
                 house1 123    72        1  kitchen
                 house1 111    63        1  livingroom
22/11/2018 20:00 House2 102    60        0  bedroom1
                 House2 104    62        0  bedroom2
                 House2 122    71        1  kitchen
                 House2 115    61        1  living room
22/11/2018 20:05 House2 103    64        0  bedroom1
                 House2 104    68        0  bedroom2
                 House2 123    72        1  kitchen
                 House2 111    63        1  livingroom
```

you can simply just do `df.pivot(columns='room')`:

```
                         co2                                humidity                                    presence
                  room  bedroom1    bedroom2    kitchen living room bedroom1    bedroom2    kitchen living room bedroom1    bedroom2    kitchen living room
index             house                                             
22/11/2018 20:00  House2    102       104        122         115        60          62          71      61          0           0           1       1
                  house1    102       104        122         115        60          62          71      61          0           0           1       1
22/11/2018 20:05  House2    103       104        123         111        64          68          72      63          0           0           1       1
                  house1    103       104        123         111        64          68          72      63          0           0           1       1
```

Comment: you can rename the columns with `df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(var,room) for var, room in df.columns]` afterwards to ends up with the OP expected output I think

Comment: @Ben.T Yes, you can do that. Excellent addition.